# Fetch selected item in page from bootstrap-modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using `bootstrap modal` to provide a functionality to user to select any desired `item` and than add the selected item to parent/current page.

I've created an example on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eamaa45h/) for better and faster understanding.
In eg: there are 2 items (three `li` for each). When user selects certain item, the modal must close, its price (which is fetched from another page) must be displayed on the square box and a new box must be added to the left side (with current `glyphicon`).

I somehow understand this must be achieved using jQuery but am blank as to how should I proceed further. I'm totally new to both `modals` and `jQuery` so if any one has any idea about it?

**UPDATE:**

I did try my hands on it and I'm able to fetch the selected item from `modal` and add to the parent/current view but it doesn't work properly for the second time(second box). Here's [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eamaa45h/1/). and here's the updated code:

jQuery:

```
var itemLayout = '<div class="square"><div class="content"><div class="table"><div class="table-cell numbers"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus prices"></div></div></div></div></div>';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".layout").append(itemLayout);

  $(".square").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');

  });
  fetchPrice();
});

function fetchPrice() {
  var users = $('.prices');
  $(document).on('click', '.fetch', function() {
    var stylesheet = $(this).text();
    console.log(stylesheet);
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    users.removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').text(stylesheet);
    $(itemLayout).insertAfter('.square');
    $(".square").click(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');

    });
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="layout"></div>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Select to display</h4>
          </div>
          <!-- modal-header end -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix'>
                <div class="pull-left">Chinese</div>
              </li>
              <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
                <div class="pull-left">Hakka Noodles </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <div class="fetch">Price1</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
                <div class=""><b>Ingredients</b></div>
             </li>
             <li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix'>
                <div class="pull-left">Others</div>
             </li>
             <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
                <div class="pull-left">Masala papad </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <div class="fetch">Price2</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
                 <div class=""><b>Ingredients</b></div>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**OLD**
Here's the code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<div class="square">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell numbers">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- square end -->


<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Select to display</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- modal-header end -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <ul class="list-group">

          <li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix'>
            <div class="pull-left">Chinese</div>
          </li>
          <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
            <div class="pull-left">Hakka Noodles </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <a href="Price.php?id">Price</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
            <div class=""><b>Ingredients</b></div>
          </li>

           <li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info clearfix'>
            <div class="pull-left">Others</div>
          </li>
          <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
            <div class="pull-left">Masala papad </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <a href="Price.php?id">Price</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class='list-group-item clearfix'>
           <div class=""><b>Ingredients</b></div>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery to open modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
   });
});
```

Comment: where is the rest of the code, what problem did you encountered?

Comment: the current code works fine, no problem.
I've explained what I need to do next and need suggestions for the same

Comment: first sugestion look into some books about javascript/jquery, then read/watch some tutorials , then if you can't do it after that i suggest you hire a experienced developer

Comment: what you want to do with your model ?

Comment: select an item (li)

Comment: @madalinivascu I did update the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eamaa45h/1/
if you can have a look at the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you use bootsrap best way make

`<div class="square" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">`

for call modal, end do modal header like this

`<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`

On this case u don't need write any jquery its will be work "from box"

Comment: it already works. that isn't a problem, I need to know which item user has selected from modal

Comment: For first you need add in modal something what user can select(select-box, checkbox or radio button)